# Is there a way to hide and Show Algolia Facets/Refinements values based on user roles?

Tags: c#, .net, algolia, nopcommerce-4.0

Hi guys am integrating Algolia to an NopCommerce store . I want to know if is there any way to hide or show a facet value based on  user whose logged in. For example i have a hierarchical menu that displays product categories for filtering  , some categories are mapped to certain customer roles which means only a customer assigned to those roles should see those categories  . I there way to implement such functionality using instantsearch.js.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can hide facet just get current customer from workcontext and check their role and through that you can hide or show Algolia Facet/Refinements.